# MultipartHttpServletRequest and DTO in requestBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using spring 4. I'm trying to receive a file upload and a DTO in my controller. Something like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public Long uploadFile(@RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO, MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
```

But I cant make this work. I only succeeded by sending each DTO param as a @RequestParam.

What is the correct client call for this controller. or is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL, form) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    if ( !! window.FormData) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', form);
        self.xmlHttpReq.send(formData);
    }
}
```